# AWS CLI Unknown component: credential_provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

Ive been trying to setup an aws lambda function for a while now but seem to just keep running into this error. I've followed [the basic tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-custom-events-deploy.html) and setup everything exactly as it is in the guide for the user I have. But no matter what I keep getting the Unknown component: credential_provider error when trying to do anything via the CLI. Has anyone else run into this or know of a more indepth/better tutorial for setting this up????

Answer (score 2):

The examples show the call being made with a --profile parameter.  In most cases you will just want to remove that.  If you need to use a profile, then create one in your ~/.aws/config file and make sure the name you give it matches up with the name being used.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I got this error when I told aws-cli to use a profile that didn't exist.  (This can be through the `--profile` option or the `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` environment variable.)

Check your `.aws/config` and `.aws/credentials` files.

Answer (score 0):

Run `aws config` first, then execute `aws lambda create-function ...` without the option `--profile`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue then I realized the issue was because I only had a `default` profile in my `~/.aws/credentials`.  Open up the file and see what the profile name is on the first line.  Then when you run the `create-function` you can do `--profile <profile name goes here>`

Answer (score 0):

While running S3 commands using CLI I received the same error

> Unknown component: credential_provider.

The command I ran was :

```
s3 sync s3://mybucket --region eu-central-1 --profile default
```

This error comes when I run this command as a sudo user.

So I would suggest run it without sudo. One more thing it does not work with any other user also like for user "test" it would give error :

> A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects
>   operation: Access Denied

or something like this for any other cli utility.

It works with default user ubuntu. Login the machine with ubuntu user or change the user to ubuntu and then try running the same lamda function.